# C# linq join returning multiple result

Tags: c#, linq

I have this query, model can have multiple B and C. Model have 2 Cs which results in returning 2 models.
Its supposed to only return 1 model with 1 A and a list of B and C
Is is possible to achieve it in linq?

Model table has ModelId, Name

B table has BId, ModelId, Name

C table has CId, ModelId, Name

```cs
var x = 
    (from model in this.GetDefaultQuery()
    join a in _context.a on model.modelId equals a.modelId
    join b in _context.b on model.modelId equals b.modelId //this should be a list of b
    join c in _context.c on model.modelId equals c.modelId //this should be a distinc list of c
    select new
    {
        M = model,
        A = A,
        B = B, //this should be a list of B's Name
        C = C, //this should be a distinc list of C's Name
    })
    .Where(x => x.model.modelId == modelId);
```

Comment: Do you have navigation properties related to those ids?  If so you can use them instead of joining.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you need JOIN must be the first question. With proper relations you don't even need it (and shouldn't).

What you are describing looks like to be:

```
var result = 
    (from model in this.GetDefaultQuery()
    select new
    {
        A = (from a in _context.a where model.aId == a.aId select a).ToList(),
        B = (from b in _context.b where model.bId == b.bId select b).ToList(),
        C = (from c in _context.c where model.cId == c.cId select c).Distinct().ToList()
    })
    .Where(x => x.modelId == modelId);
```

EDIT: It was hard to write in comprehension syntax. In method syntax it is easier:

```
var result = this.GetDefaultQuery()
      .Where(x => x.modelId == modelId)
      .Select(model => new {
          A = _context.a.Where(x => x.aId == model.aId).ToList(),
          B = _context.b.Where(x => x.bId == model.bId).Distinct().ToList(),
          C = _context.c.Where(x => x.cId == model.cId).ToList()
});
```

PS: Generated SQL would likely be very inefficient.

EDIT: Working sample. Note that connection string is what I have, and also your model doesn't really have navigation properties as you suggested, here I have navigation properties but not used to mimic your case. Otherwise those ctx.Customers.Where(...) would simply be o.Customer as an example.

```
string defaultConString = @"server=.\SQLExpress2012;Database=Northwind;Trusted_Connection=yes;";

void Main()
{
    var ctx = new MyContext(defaultConString);

    var result = ctx.Orders
        .Where(o => o.OrderId == 10249)
        .Select(o => new
        {
            A = ctx.Customers.Where(c => c.CustomerId == o.CustomerId).ToList(), // Single in fact. Could be SingleOrDefault()
            B = ctx.Employees.Where(e => e.EmployeeId == o.EmployeeId).ToList(),
            C = ctx.OrderDetails.Where(od => od.OrderId == o.OrderId).ToList()

        }

        );

    // Check result - Linqpad sample
    //result.Dump(); 
}


public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public MyContext(string connectionString)
       : base(connectionString)
    { }
    public DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Order> Orders { get; set; }
    public DbSet<OrderDetail> OrderDetails { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
}



public class Customer
{
    [Key]
    public string CustomerId { get; set; }
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
    public string ContactName { get; set; }
    // ...
    //public virtual List<Order> Orders { get; set; }
}

public class Order
{
    [Key]
    public int OrderId { get; set; }
    public string CustomerId { get; set; }
    public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
    public DateTime OrderDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime? ShippedDate { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("CustomerId")]
    public Customer Customer { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("EmployeeId")]
    public Employee Employee { get; set; }
    public virtual List<OrderDetail> OrderDetails { get; set; }
}

[Table("Order Details")]
public class OrderDetail
{
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 1)]
    public int OrderId { get; set; }
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 2)]
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public decimal UnitPrice { get; set; }
    public Int16 Quantity { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ProductId")]
    public Product Product { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("OrderId")]
    public Order Order { get; set; }
}

public class Product
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    // ...
}

public class Employee
{
    [Key]
    public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for you input i will try these, also updated the questions about Ids.

Comment: im getting "multiple implementation of the query pattern dbset<> ambigous call to where" error.

Comment: @user10860402, You didn't supply sample data and your model.

Comment: B and C both have model ID property. model can have many B and C. B and C can only have 1 model. also updated question sorry for error before

Comment: @user10860402, please supply sample and model.

Comment: I updated the question. not sure if thats the model your looking for.

Comment: @user10860402, OK you are not supplying a model nor sample. Then I am supplying one, you can build looking at it. It is tested to be working.